# can't link nginx with ghost in docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I am deploying a ghost server on digitalocean with port default to 2368.

```
docker run -d --name ghost ghost
```

and also I deploy a nginx server as well.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name nginx --link ghost:ghost -v /home/abc/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled nginx
```

under the path of /home/abc/nginx/sites-enabled, I have a config file - named as ghost

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name mydomain; 
  access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.log; 

  location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://ghost:2368;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

at last

```
docker restart nginx,ghost
```

I can clearly the nginx and ghost container is running well, and go to the IP address of server, I can see the welcome page of nginx, which says

```
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
```

but go to the domain, it can' find the server or sometimes show the nginx welcome page as well

Answer (score 0):

First, Your volume mapping should be `-v /home/abc/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/conf.d`, not `site-enabled`.

Second, because Nginx loads DNS entries when it starts up and never updates, Nginx won't be able to locate your ghost container after ghost restarts (and thus gets a new IP address). A quickfix is to run `docker restart ghost nginx` instead of `docker restart nginx ghost`.

Comment: I had done the second advice like you said, it doesn't work. about the first, where is the default Nginx site configuration file

Comment: @user824624 How is your Nginx image made? Do you have the Dockerfile public?

Comment: Hi, it is still not working.  Nothing shows using the command : docker logs nginx. When go to the domain, the page only shows the 'the web is not available' rather than the welcome nginx page

Comment: @user824624 your conf file name must end with `.conf`. Your log doesn't work because you set the access log. Remove the access log line and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pre-setup nginx proxy https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

Following the instructions I run the nginx proxy:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Then you can simply run the ghost docker something like this:

```
docker run --name some-blog -d -p 80:2368 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.com -v /home/ghost/someblog/:/var/lib/ghost --restart unless-stopped ghost
```

I have multiple ghost containers setup like this.